# Which hedge is in the behind on the picture?

Tags: identification

I see a trimmed and an untrimmed hedge in the back. What type can it be?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYJqd.jpg]

Comment: Prize-winning photo!

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking about the red-leaved hedge, that's *Rhus typhina* ([staghorn sumac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhus_typhina)), a northeastern North American shrub/small tree.

If you're asking about the trimmed evergreens in the far background, I think it's either a yew of some kind or, given the olive-green color of the leaves, English boxwood.

The untrimmed shrubs may or may not be evergreen; without a closeup of the plants and leaves, it's very difficult to make an ID.

Comment: Yes, Sumac turns scarlet in the Fall.

Comment: Hi, I am asking about the untrimmed shrubs, would you look at 00:15 here, you see the same garden. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8JjyHfOMJ8